# Azure Function Table Storage in binding violates the constraint of type parameter 'TElement'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I am working on reading data from Table Storage in my Azure Function. I have created HttpTrigger function with in Table Storage binding. Project is using storage package:

```
"WindowsAzure.Storage": "8.0.0"
```

and binding:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "metadataTable",
      "type": "table",
      "direction": "in",
      "tableName": "metadata",
      "connection": "StorageConnectionString",
      "partitionkey": "some_partition_key"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Having code generated by template I have added new in parameter:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, 
                    IQueryable<MetadataTable> metadataTable, TraceWriter log)
{
.....
}
public class MetadataTable: TableEntity
{
    public MetadataTable():base() { }

    public MetadataTable(string partitionkey, string rowkey):base(partitionkey,rowkey) {}

    public string Data { get; set;  }
}
```

During save and run process I am getting compile error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   GenericArguments[0], 'Submission#0+MetadataTable', on
>   'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Tables.TableAttributeBindingProvider+TableToIQueryableConverter`1[TElement]'
>   violates the constraint of type 'TElement'. mscorlib:
>   GenericArguments[0], 'Submission#0+MetadataTable', on
>   'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Tables.TableAttributeBindingProvider+TableToIQueryableConverter`1[TElement]'
>   violates the constraint of type parameter 'TElement'.

Can anyone help me with this or meet same error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message looks a bit weird, but try removing `WindowsAzure.Storage` reference from `project.json` file. This package is referenced automatically by the runtime, and if you include it explicitly you get all kinds of errors due to version mismatch.

I created a clean Azure Function from your code without the package reference and it compiled and worked just fine. Try the same.

Comment: Thank you Mikhail. Do you know how can I set specific version for the assemblies, that are automatically added by the Azure Functions hosting environment (Newtonsoft.Json, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, etc)?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of such possibility

Comment: I have the same issue with a Visual Studio 2017 created Function App that has no project.json or a reference to WindowsAzure.Storage.

[31/08/2017 12:49:20] Run: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'SearchTrucks.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: GenericArguments[0], 'NNN.NNN.NNN', on 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Tables.TableExtension+TableToIQueryableConverter`1[TElement]' violates the constraint of type 'TElement'. mscorlib: